# Pandas: add column based on groupby with condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with four columns: id1, id2, age, stime.  For example

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 1, 3, pd.to_datetime('2020-01-10 00:30:16')], 
                         [2, 1, 10, pd.to_datetime('2020-01-27 00:20:20')], 
                         [3, 1, 60, pd.to_datetime('2020-01-26 00:10:08')],
                         [4, 2, 1, pd.to_datetime('2020-01-13 00:20:19')], 
                         [5, 2, 2, pd.to_datetime('2020-01-12 00:40:17')],
                         [6, 2, 3, pd.to_datetime('2020-01-10 00:10:53')], 
                         [7, 3, 20, pd.to_datetime('2020-01-21 00:20:57')],
                         [8, 3, 40, pd.to_datetime('2020-01-20 00:10:38')], 
                         [9, 3, 60, pd.to_datetime('2020-01-01 00:30:38')],
                       ]),
                       columns=['id1', 'id2', 'age', 'stime'])
```

I want to add a column where the value is the maximum value of age, that also has a matching id2 and was within the last 2 weeks of the stime for that row.  So for the above example I want to get

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 1, 3, pd.to_datetime('2020-01-10 00:30:16'), 3], 
                         [2, 1, 10, pd.to_datetime('2020-01-27 00:20:20'), 60], 
                         [3, 1, 60, pd.to_datetime('2020-01-26 00:10:08'), 60],
                         [4, 2, 1, pd.to_datetime('2020-01-13 00:20:19'), 3], 
                         [5, 2, 2, pd.to_datetime('2020-01-12 00:40:17'), 3],
                         [6, 2, 3, pd.to_datetime('2020-01-10 00:10:53'), 3], 
                         [7, 3, 20, pd.to_datetime('2020-01-21 00:20:57'), 40],
                         [8, 3, 40, pd.to_datetime('2020-01-20 00:10:38'), 40], 
                         [9, 3, 60, pd.to_datetime('2020-01-01 00:30:38'), 60]
                       ]),
                       columns=['id1', 'id2', 'age', 'stime', 'max_age_last_2w'])
```

As the df I want to do this is on is very large, any help on how to do this efficiently would be greatly appreciated - thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
df['max_age_last_2w'] = df.groupby(['id2', pd.Grouper(key='stime', freq='2W', closed='right')])['age'].transform('max')
```

Output:

```
  id1 id2 age               stime  max_age_last_2w
0   1   1   3 2020-01-10 00:30:16                3
1   2   1  10 2020-01-27 00:20:20               60
2   3   1  60 2020-01-26 00:10:08               60
3   4   2   1 2020-01-13 00:20:19                3
4   5   2   2 2020-01-12 00:40:17                3
5   6   2   3 2020-01-10 00:10:53                3
6   7   3  20 2020-01-21 00:20:57               40
7   8   3  40 2020-01-20 00:10:38               40
8   9   3  60 2020-01-01 00:30:38               60
```